# Can I put multiple prepared statements inside one stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Example code:

```
BEGIN

PREPARE stmt_user_login FROM 
"SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `t_users`
WHERE `t_users`.`username` = ? AND `t_users`.`password` = ?;";

SET @a := $username;
SET @b := $password;

EXECUTE stmt_user_login USING @a, @b;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_user_login;

IF FOUND_ROWS() = '1' THEN

PREPARE stmt_user_loggedin FROM
"INSERT INTO
`t_sessions`
(`username`, `last_request`, `last_ip`, `last_port`, `token`, `validity`)
VALUES
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

SET @c := $user_name;
SET @d := $last_request;
SET @e := $last_ip;
SET @f := $last_port;
SET @g := $token;
SET @h := $validity;

EXECUTE stmt_user_loggedin USING @c, @d, @e, @f, @g, @h;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_user_loggedin;

END IF;

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using simple statements inside the stored procedure, and using prepared statements in PHP to call the procedure.

Here is my SQL PROCEDURE as exported from phpMyAdmin:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_login`(IN `$username` VARCHAR(32) CHARSET utf8, IN `$password` VARCHAR(32) CHARSET utf8, IN `$token` VARCHAR(32) CHARSET utf8, IN `$last_request` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET utf8)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

SET @username := $username;
SET @password := $password;
SET @token := $token;
SET @last_request := $last_request;
SET @validity := '1800';

DELETE FROM `t_sessions` WHERE (`t_sessions`.`last_request` + @validity) < (@last_request + @validity)
AND `t_sessions`.`user` = @username
AND 
(SELECT COUNT(`t_users`.`user_id`)
FROM `t_users` 
WHERE `t_users`.`username` = @username 
AND `t_users`.`password` = @password) = 1;

INSERT INTO `t_sessions` (`t_sessions`.`user`, `t_sessions`.`token`, `t_sessions`.`validity`, `t_sessions`.`last_request`)
SELECT `t_users`.`username`, @token, @validity, @last_request
FROM `t_users`
WHERE `t_users`.`username` = @username
AND `t_users`.`password` = @password;

SELECT 
CASE LAST_INSERT_ID()
WHEN 0 THEN 0
ELSE 1
END AS `LOGGEDIN`;

END
```

AND the PHP part:

```
include('conn.php'); // "conn.php is the file where I'm storing the connection script to mysql"
        $conn->select_db("test");
        $query_stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL `sp_login`(?, ?, ?, ?);");
        $query_stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $token, $last_request);
        $query_stmt->execute();
        $query_stmt->bind_result($result);
        while ($query_stmt->fetch()) {
            switch ($result) {
            CASE 0:
                $query_stmt->close();
                echo 'BAD';
                break;
            CASE 1:
                $query_stmt->close();
                echo 'OK';
                break;          
            }
            if ($conn) {$conn->close();}
            exit;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple prepared statements in a stored procedure.

But that's not the problem in your procedure.

`FOUND_ROWS()` returns the number of rows returned by the previous query, not the count. In your procedure, the number of rows will always be 1, even if it reports a count of 0 in the previous query.<sup>*</sup>

Instead, you should use `SELECT ... INTO` to capture the value.

Also, you don't need to use prepared statements to include procedure arguments safely in your query. You could do this:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE usercount INT;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_users
WHERE t_users.username = $username AND t_users.password = $password
INTO usercount

IF usercount = 1 THEN

  INSERT INTO t_sessions (username, last_request, last_ip, last_port, token, validity)
  VALUES ($user_name, $last_request, $last_ip, $last_port, $token, $validity);

END IF;

END
```

I'm assuming `$username` and `$password` and the other identifiers prefixed with `$` are the names of procedure arguments. It's unusual to use `$` prefix on SQL identifiers, but it is legal.

Your procedure could even be simplified further:

```
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO t_sessions (username, last_request, last_ip, last_port, token, validity)
  SELECT $user_name, $last_request, $last_ip, $last_port, $token, $validity
  FROM t.users WHERE t.users.username = $username AND t_users.password = password
  LIMIT 1;

END
```

The way this works is if there's a match in the SELECT, it returns one row, which has columns populated by the values in those `$`-prefixed variables. Then that row is INSERTed into `t_sessions`. If there's no match, it returns zero rows, so no INSERT happens.

---

<sup>*</sup> Exception: `FOUND_ROWS()` seems to return 0 on a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query if the query optimizes out using a NULL access type or "impossible where" like if you use `WHERE 1=0`. I logged a bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73283

And there's more, I found quite a lot of other bugs reported against MySQL 5.6 for `FOUND_ROWS()` returning wrong results. I would not recommend using this function.